# Display unicode characters on ggplot in an R Markdown pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

When a ggplot includes unicode characters (such as the International Phonetic Alphabet), the R markdown script is not knitted into a pdf correctly.

```
---
title: "Markdown IPA"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
- \setmonofont{Arial Unicode MS}
date: "2022-08-12"
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(ggplot2)
```

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), label = 'aɪ.pʰiː.ɛɪ')
```

This yields the following:

[image: Result]

Below is the desired result:

[image: Desiredr]

Comment: I think the issue is that the font you want to use does not include those Unicode characters. For example, if you replace your `label` with `label = "äëöüß"` there are no errors. You need to find a font that supports those symbols; then include the font through `fontspec`.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed with the `showtext` package.

```
---
title: "Markdown IPA"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
- \setmonofont{Arial Unicode MS}
date: "2022-08-12"
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)
font_add_google('Noto Sans')
showtext_auto()
```

```
ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), label = 'aɪ.pʰiː.ɛɪ', family = 'Noto Sans')
```

[image: Result]